# Add First Char Capital Letter to input & array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

What i would like to do is have the user input their own fruits and have the array of fruits on there as well. i will sort it out but before this i would like to make each word's first character a capital letter then spit it out on the html with " with " on each entry. Im not sure if i am on the right track. Any help is greatly appreciated ! thanks

```
let fruits = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "kiwi"];

function addFruits () {
let fruitInput = prompt ("Please Enter More Fruits").toLowerCase().split(" ");
let fruitsAdded = fruits.push(fruitInput);
let fruitsPushed = fruitsAdded.map(
    function(value){ 
        return value.replace(value.charAt(0), value.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
    });
fruits.sort();
document.getElementById("sortedFruits").innerHTML = fruits.join(" with ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took you code and it working by

- pushing the values of the array with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), for getting all items as single paramters,
- removing the assignment of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), because it returns the new length of the array, not a new array or the given array,
- moving sorting above, because you need here the sorted array,
- now getting the upper case words from `fruits`
- inside of the callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) take the first character as upper case string and the resz of the string with [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

```js
function addFruits() {
    let fruitInput = prompt("Please Enter More Fruits").toLowerCase().split(" ");
    fruits.push(...fruitInput);
    fruits.sort();
    let upperCased = fruits.map(function(value) {
        return value[0].toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    });
    document.getElementById("sortedFruits").innerHTML = upperCased.join(" with ");
}

let fruits = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "kiwi"];
addFruits();
```

```html
<div id="sortedFruits"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it helps to break things up a bit. You want to take input and update a list, then you want to format that list for display. I added a list and event trigger to make it easy to demo.

```js
// set up your list of fruit and the handles for your event/render
let fruits = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "kiwi"];
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#sortedFruits');
const button = document.querySelector('#add_button');

const render = () => {
  // build (and sort) a list from the fruits array
  const list = fruits
    .sort()
    // uppercase the first character and ensure the rest are lower
    .map(str => str.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase())
    // format item for render
    .map(fruit => `<li>${fruit}</li>`)
    .join('');
  
  // replace list with new list
  wrapper.innerHTML = list;
}

const addFruits = () => {
  // take user input
  const input = prompt('Please enter more fruit')
  // build array of fruit to add
  const newFruit = input
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(' ');
  
  // update fruit list
  fruits = [ ...fruits, ...newFruit ];
  // show updated list
  render();
}

// initial list
render();
// add event handler to trigger fruit addition
button.addEventListener('click', addFruits);
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="button" name="add_fruit" value="Add More Fruit!" id="add_button" />
  <ul id="sortedFruits"></ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Works as well, Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score -1):

```
    function Firstupchar(letter) {
        return letter[0].toUpperCase() + letter.substring(1).toLowerCase()
    }

["one","two"].map(c => Firstupchar(c) ).join(" with ")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.